# CRC combine vs update performance

Tags: java, zlib, crc, crc32

I have a large blob of data that I'm dividing into smaller parts to send over the network. Before sending, I compile the list of smaller parts and want to ensure that there is no data integrity issue.

My question is

- should I do CRC32C combine for each smaller part and compare with the CRC32C of the large data blob? or
- just keep updating the CRC32C with update function (defined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/CRC32C.html#update(byte%5B%5D,int,int))) for each smaller part and finally check whether that equals the CRC32C of the large blob?

Also, any pointers on zlib's equivalent of Java's CRC32C combine function implementation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only sending the CRC-32C of the "large blob", then do your second bullet, which is to update a single CRC value for each "smaller part". The only way there would be a speed advantage to combining the CRCs of the smaller parts would be if you were computing those CRCs in parallel on differents cores or threads.

Comment: I see, quick clarification: I'm not sending the CRC-32C of the "large blob", I'm sending each "smaller parts" and it's CRC-32C. But, looks like from your explanation, even in this case, we don't need to do CRC combine as I'm not computing those in parallel on different cores or threads. The operations are sequential in my case.

Comment: If the order of the smaller blobs matter, then you may want to in fact send the combined CRC-32C, or have some other check on the order. All of the parts may have been sent fine and verified by the CRC-32C of each, but if they are assembled in the wrong order, e.g. they were received out of order, you wouldn't know.

Comment: It can be assumed that the order is guaranteed by other guards in place. The full sequence of steps is : 1) calculate large blob's CRC-32C. 2) Split into "smaller parts" and calculate their CRC-32C. (All parts have been generated now) 3) Iterate over each part and send it over the network.

Comment: Wait, why are you calculating the large blob's CRC-32C at all, if you're not sending it?

Comment: Want to verify if that equates to the smaller parts CRCs put together.

Comment: You can forget about the part of sending the smaller parts over the network. Basically, just want to check if splitting the large blob doesn't corrupt the data.

Comment: I don't see what you're verifying. That there wasn't a memory corruption during your calculation?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Want to verify data doesn't get corrupted during split.